# how to make gridview take 100% of the width of a panel

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a `gridview` which is placed in a panel. I want this `gridview` to be 100% width and height of the panel

Here is what I have tried:

**CSS**

```
.pnlGridView {

       position:relative;
        float:right;
        height:40%;
        width:40%;

        border:6px solid RGB(140,240,2110);


    }

    .gvDates {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
        <asp:Panel CssClass="pnlGridView" runat="server"><asp:GridView ID="gvDates" runat="server"  OnRowCommand="gvDates_RowCommand" CssClass="gvDates"/></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember to have put the gridview inside a div once, and set the height and width in this div. that worked. In your case gridview>div>panel would fit. give a try

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declared the CSS file,

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Site.css" />
```

Add the above line into `<head>` tag in your html and try again.
its worked for me.